# Python regex - extend string

Tags: python, regex, string, extend

I got a .txt file, where the line is a sequence of names in a row:

> John Marry Joseph

And I need to extend each of them with @company.com, to get this result:

> John@company.com Marry@company.com Joseph@company.com

Is there a way how to write it with regex or some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KISS

```
[(y+"@company.com") for y in x.split()]
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/lSpUxT)**

If you don't want a list then you can `join` it, like this

```
print(' '.join([(y+"@company.com") for y in x.split()]))
```

or this

```
print('@company.com '.join(x.split()) + '@company.com')
```

Using regex `re.sub`

```
x = "John Marry Joseph"
print(re.sub("([^\s]+)", "\\1@company.com", x))
```

Comment: This will return an array. Just do " ".join(all that array) to get a string back

Comment: @karina well 2nd one can be used then..though good suggestion

Comment: Oh sorry. None of that was there when I commented

Comment: the second join version works almost ;-) it needs an extra @company.com added to the end.